# Outputting contents of a file in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to output the contents of a file to another file identified by computer name and date inside a directory. I can get the file contents to transfer over successfully if I don't use the date in the title of the file. If I try and include the date then the title just leaves it out. This is probably some kind of DOS mistake that someone might be able to pick up on. If you can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
    SET dtStamp24=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%


   type %filename% >> .\%directoryName%\%hostName%%dtStamp24%.LOG
```

Comment: Looks fine here. How exactly is it not working? Enabling command echo (`echo on`) at the beginning of your script may help with debugging.

Comment: I get "dtStamp24=20145/01" which isn't going to be so good... maybe something to do with your locale/country settings.

Comment: Yeah, see that's the thing. I opened up cmd and set the time stamp to a variable and then echoed it and everything appeared fine. Maybe it has something to do with the double %% in the file name with the hostname. The output in console was 20140527.

Comment: Just tried the whole thing in another batch script in Win8 and the file name was perfect. Stupid XP.